# Can one successfully exercise on interlocking foam mats when they are placed over carpeting?

Tags: exercise, bodyweight-exercises, gym, exercise-equipment, equipment

When interlocking foam mats are placed over carpeting, will they work for physical exercise?  Or will they detach from each other all the time?

In this context, I'm defining exercise as:

- Stretching
- Push ups
- Sit ups
- Kettlebell exercises
- Dumbbell exercises
- Yoga
- Thai Chi
- Planking
- Isometrics
- Body weight exercises (e.g. squats)

This is just for a home setup... nothing commercial.

Here's an example of the interlocking foam mats:
[image: interlocking foam mats]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, my home gym has interlocking foam mats placed over carpet. I have never had problems with them detaching. Some things of note though, my carpet is not particularly fluffy, and my mats are about 2x thicker than most gym mats you will find online. Both of these factors probably impact how well they stay together. One thing I have noticed is near the edges of the room the mats do warp upwards when stepping on the opposite side of a mat, but they stay attached so it isn't really an issue.

Comment: If you did have a particularly fluffy carpet, I'd imagine you could put down some poly + plywood and then the mats on top as well?

Comment: I'd imagine that would probably help. I'm not sure what that would do to the carpet/pad in terms of damage though. I assume it would be fine, but worth looking up.

Comment: Thank you Eric.  Real helpful info in your answer.  Upvoted.  Where did you find the thicker interlocking mats?  I wonder if buying two layers of the thinner mats would work as well.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I just ran over to my local Big 5, but it looks like amazon has [some thick ones too](https://www.amazon.com/Prosource-Interlocking-Protective-Cushioned-Equipment/dp/B07GZ2FZT5/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=extra+thick+interlocking+foam+tiles&qid=1642525054&sprefix=extra+thick+interlo%2Caps%2C117&sr=8-2). [Big 5 tiles](https://www.big5sportinggoods.com/store/details/shock-athletic-extra-thick-gym-flooring---6-pack/2320146080002/_/A-4521225)

Comment: As far as two layers of thinner mats, I wouldn't imagine that would work well. I would imagine that would probably be worse than one layer since it is the lack of support that would make them disconnect in the first place. The 2nd layer would have even less support if the pads are squishy enough.

Comment: Thank you for the updates Eric.  Have the foam tiles stained the carpeting at all, or would your carpeting be too dark to notice?

Comment: Finally got around to checking, no, the carpet underneath looks the same if not better than the carpet leading up to my gym. The tiles should just protect the carpet underneath from wear and tear.